# Put an image at the end of a line in line graph (react-native-svg-charts)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts

I have a Line Chart using `react-native-svg-charts` and I want to include a 40px by 40px PNG image at the end of the line. Here's my current code:

```
<View style={styles.chartContainer}>
    <LineChart
        data={chartData}
        style={{ height: 100 }}
        svg={{ strokeWidth: 5, stroke: 'url(#gradient)' }}
        curve={shape.curveNatural}
        yMin={0}
        yMax={15}
        xMax={chartData.length + 1}
        contentInset={{ top: 30, bottom: 0, left: 50 }}>
        <Gradient />
    </LineChart>
    <View style={styles.chartFloor}></View>
</View>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

And I need to get it to look like this:

[image]

I could use the values in the chart data to calcule the absolute position and then just use a regular Image but maybe there's an easier way using SVG.

For the record, the PNG icon can also be an SVG (I have it in SVG as well).

Comment: Reading the docs, it looks like this package supports adding an svg to the chart using the prop `children` and the library `react-native-svg`.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that I still need to calculate where to place the icon, I ended up making a function that calculates the position but I'll leave the question in case someone has a better solution.